# Schema compare: how to prevent FILLFACTOR being scripted with table definition

Tags: database-project

I have created a large number of indexes on foreign keys in my development database and I now want to use the schema compare tool to update the table definition files in the database project.

The problem is that the comparison tool, in addition to adding the CREATE INDEX statement, is adding the statement WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90) to the primary keys.

I would prefer not to specify the fill factor in the table definition files. Is that possible?

I have already ticked "Ignore fill factor", "Ignore index options" and "Ignore table options" in the Schema Compare Options without success

Comment: Are you using a clustered index?

Comment: @Jared the keys on primary keys are clustered, those on foreign keys aren't